# Unity Photon InstantiateSceneObject() not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have a multiplayer game in Unity. I use PhotonEngine for this.

In the game there is a chicken, it's the player. It can pick up seeds from the ground. Then it takes the seed to a place in a given time and gets one point.

The problem is that I would like to instantiate this seed as a scene object. Here is the code where I do this:

```
public virtual void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(player.name, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation, 0);
    lobbyCamera.SetActive(false);
    PhotonNetwork.InstantiateSceneObject(seed.name, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation, 1, null);
    Debug.Log("1 seed spawned.");
}
```

But somehow it is not working. The program doesn't give an error, or warning. Moreover I see the message written to the debug.log. So in principle it's spawned. But it isn't appearing in the hierarchy, it isn't appearing anywhere. So it didn't do that. What have I done wrong?

p.s. I added the seed prefab to the code. It is in the resources folder. So that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that comes to my  mind is that *maybe* you're not the master client? Try to change your code in

```
if (PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient)
{
   PhotonNetwork.InstantiateSceneObject(seed.name, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation, 1, null);
}
```

else every player joining the room will try to spawn an object in the scene without having the permission to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are instantiating that object to the Interest Group number 1.
Maybe your client is not registered to that group, so it will not receive those events.

```
 PhotonNetwork.InstantiateSceneObject(seed.name, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation, 1, null);
```

try changing the number 1 in that line to 0. (0 is interest group all, it means it broadcasts to all users)
You can't unregister from group 0.